# Console does not show id when js update

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a drag n drop feature. The dragable div have an id but when i check the log in console it's just an empty row. Why?

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="ui-state-default">1</div>
<td><div id="sverige1_w1_mon" class="connectedSortable"></div></td>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( "#lista_objekt, #sverige1_w1_mon, #sverige2_w1_mon, #sverige3_w1_mon, #sverige4_w1_mon, #norge1_w1_mon, #norge2_w1_mon, #sverige1_w1_tu, #sverige2_w1_tue, #sverige3_w1_tue, #sverige4_w1_tue, #norge1_w1_tue, #norge2_w1_tue").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function(event, ui){
        var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        console.log(postData);

        $.post('php/sortable_order.php', {list: postData}, function(o) {
            console.log(o);
        }, 'json');
    }
});
$( "#lista_objekt, #sverige1_w1_mon, #sverige2_w1_mon, #sverige3_w1_mon, #sverige4_w1_mon, #norge1w1_mon, #norge2_w1_mon, #sverige1_w1_tue, #sverige2_w1_tue, #sverige3_w1_tue, #sverige4_w1_tue, #norge1_w1_tue, #norge2_w1_tue").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: The IDs aber probably not in the right form http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize

Answer (score 0):

id MUST contain underscore "_"

```
<div id="item_1" class="ui-state-default">1</div>
```